# The year function doesn't support dt_wstr

Tags: sql-server, date, ssis, expression, etl

I am unable to apply transformation using below code. getting error

> The year function doesn't support  dt_wstr.

The expression iam using is:

```
(DT_I4)((DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(fisc_wk_end_dt) + 
       RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)MONTH(fisc_wk_end_dt),2) + 
       RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DAY(fisc_wk_end_dt),2))
```

Comment: Is `fisc_wk_end_dt` of dt_wstr type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Problem

From the expression you mentioned, it looks like `fisc_wk_end_dt` column data type is string while YEAR, MONTH, DAY function's parameters must be of type date.

---

From the official documentation:

*Syntax*

> YEAR(date)

*Arguments*

> date Is a date in any date format.

*Result Types*

> DT_I4

---

### Possible solutions

#### (1) Using TOKEN() function

I will assume that `fisc_wk_end_dt` contains a date stored as string, as example:

```
1/1/2016
```

And you are looking to convert it to an integer `yyyyMMdd``:

```
20160101
```

Then you can use `TOKEN()` function to achieve that:

```
TOKEN(fisc_wk_end_dt,"/",3) + RIGHT("0" + TOKEN(fisc_wk_end_dt,"/",2),2) + RIGHT("0" + TOKEN(fisc_wk_end_dt,"/",1),2)
```

#### (2) Trying to parse the column to date

You can try to parse the column into DT_DATE or DT_DBTIMESTAMP types, this may works if date is stored in a format that can be parsed.

```
(DT_I4)((DT_WSTR,4)YEAR((DT_DBTIMESTAMP)fisc_wk_end_dt) + 
   RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)MONTH((DT_DBTIMESTAMP)fisc_wk_end_dt),2) + 
   RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DAY((DT_DBTIMESTAMP )fisc_wk_end_dt),2))
```

---

### References

- [YEAR (SSIS Expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/year-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017)
- [MONTH (SSIS Expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/month-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017)
- [DAY (SSIS Expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/day-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017)
- [TOKEN (SSIS Expression)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/token-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017)