# SSIS DT_STR to DT_DBDATE using Derived column

Tags: sql-server, date, ssis, etl, derived-column

I have a fixed format .txt file which has a date field. This field may have a date or be blank. I have wracked my brains to get this field to convert from `DT_STR` to `DT_DBDATE` in the Derived Column transformation. I have tried multiple scenarios:

```
[CHNG_DT] == "" ?  ISNULL((DT_DBDATE)[CHNG_DT] ) : (DT_DBDATE)SUBSTRING([CHNG_DT], 1, 4)) + "-" + (DB_DBDATE)(SUBSTRING(CHNG_DT], 6, 2)) + "-" + (DB_DBDATE)(SUBSTRING([CHNG_DT], 9, 2))

[CHNG_DT] == "" ? NULL(DB_DBDATE) : (DB_DBDATE)[CHNG_DT]

ISNULL([CHNG_DT]) ? NULL(DT_DBDATE) : (DT_DBDATE)((DT_STR, 10, 1252)[CHNG_DT])

ISNULL(CHNG_DT) ? NULL(DT_DBDATE) : (DT_DBDATE)((DT_STR,10,1252)CHNG_DT)

LEFT([CHNG_DT], 10) == "          " ? ISNULL((DT_DBDATE)[CHNG_DT]) : (DT_DBDATE)[CHNG_DT]

(DT_DBDATE)CHNG_DT
```

Comment: In what format the date values are stored? Can you provide a data sample?

Comment: The date in the file is formatted yyyy-mm-dd or it can be blank.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you are looking to convert values from `DT_STR` to `DT_DBDATE`, you should make sure that those values are stored in the `yyyy-MM-dd` format. You can refer to the following official documentation to learn more:

- [Converting Between Strings and Date/Time Data Types in SSIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/integration-services-data-types?view=sql-server-2017#converting-between-strings-and-datetime-data-types)

The second suggestion is to use the `LTRIM()` and `RTRIM()` functions to make sure that there are no white blanks in the beginning and end of the date values. As an example:

```
LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACENULL([CHNG_DT],""))) == "" ? NULL(DT_DBDATE) : (DT_DBDATE)LTRIM(RTRIM([CHNG_DT]))
```

If date values are stored in a different format, you should write an expression that changes the format before converting it to `DT_DBDATE`. As an example:

- [How to convert string in format dd.mm.yyyy to date using SSIS expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610394/how-to-convert-string-in-format-dd-mm-yyyy-to-date-using-ssis-expression/58615772#58615772)

#### Other helpful answers:

- [SSIS Source Format Implicit Conversion for Datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42035354/ssis-source-format-implicit-conversion-for-datetime/42038060#42038060)
- [Convert DDMonYY and time to datetime column in SSIS package (Derived Column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56175965/convert-ddmonyy-and-time-to-datetime-column-in-ssis-package-derived-column/56176375#56176375)
- [The year function doesn't support dt_wstr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57754518/the-year-function-doesnt-support-dt-wstr/57757706#57757706)

Comment: The date in the file is formatted yyyy-mm-dd or it can be blank. Either way, it is the same 10 positions within the file. If it is blank, then I need to convert it to NULL to store in the table.

Comment: We determined that part of the issue here was the field definition on the table,  CMBL_CHDT date not null. I changed this to  CMBL_CHDT null, and was then able to use CHNG_DT == "          " ? NULL(DT_DBDATE) : (DT_DBDATE)CHNG_DT to get the dates loaded correctly.